# Coolant keeps coming out

Tags: coolant-reservoir

I drive a 2015 Chevy Trax and the coolant reservoir was always dry so I thought it was a crack in the bottom, so I got it changed.  The new reservoir also dumped the coolant so I took it back to the dealers (turns out the dripping I saw was the safety thing).  The dealer thought that it may be an air block when they changed the reservoir so he added coolant and let it run and watched until it started to cycle through.  I went home and a few hours later, the coolant was on my driveway again.  What could be causing this?  Would the thermostat be causing this issue?

Comment: Bad thermostat or blown head gasket, something is causing it to overheat and push fluid out.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! The drip is actually coolant? I mean, you've verified the moisture on the ground is coolant and not just water? The reason I ask is, if you've been running your AC in a moist climate, you could be getting a drip from your evaporator core discharge tube.

Comment: Advice for next trip to the dealer for a repair, don't suggest what is wrong or what to replace, ask for a diagnosis of the problem first, that way they are on the hook if the repair does not fix the issue.

Comment: Does the engine run hot? Do you see bubbles in the coolant tank when the engine is at operating temperature and running? I wouldn't expect it on such a new vehicle, but that can indicate problems with your head gasket or potentially a cracked block/head.

Answer (score 1):

Next step would be to do a pressure test on the cooling and system and see if you can identify where the coolant is leaking out from.

Comment: Autozone loans pressure testing kits for free and it's an easy procedure. Certainly worth a try.